# How to find the scsi timeout for all the connected devices ?- redhat v 3

Tags: redhat, scsi, san

Can some one help me out in finding the default SCSI timeouts for the connected devices(disks)?
Red-hat version: 3
Kernel: 2.4.21.

Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

That's an ancient version, I'm not even sure there is an easy way to find the timeouts and in most likelihood they are all set to defaults of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scsi/sg.h header file in your distribution to be sure, but I believe that 2.4.21 is late enough in the 2.4 series that the SCSI timeout is 60 seconds.  I have a 2.4.27 source tree lying around which is 60 seconds:

```
sg.h:#define SG_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT (60*HZ) /* HZ == 'jiffies in 1 second' */
```